# Аналоги SPA на wasm

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, blazor

Есть ли аналоги Blazor (фреймворки для создания SPA приложений на WebAssembly)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Qt for WebAssembly](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/wasm.html), [Flutter Web](https://flutter.dev/web), [Unity](https://blogs.unity3d.com/ru/2018/08/15/webassembly-is-here/) и другие, но для себя я выбрал связку TypeScript + React, так как после изучения это тупо проще. Если не нравятся бандлеры, посмотрите [material-ui-umd](https://github.com/tripolskypetr/material-ui-umd)

Answer (score 1):

Сам по себе Blazor уже является фреймворком для написания SPA. Если хотите расширить возможности, которые идут из коробки, можете посмотреть на список библиотек, документации, примеров

- https://github.com/AdrienTorris/awesome-blazor